# In IOS 13 Google Map camera position is not showing Accurate when ViewController is Presented not pushed.Both screenshot attached

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, ios13

I am working on Taxi App, Where I want to present and show three markers but always the camera position is always top left corner, I have to scroll map view to see the markers.Already tried these things.

- Put my code in viewwillappear & viewdidappear and remove it from viewdidload.
- Put all my code in DispatchQueue after 2 seconds
- Use Animation & increase/Decrease time.

The sample code has been attached just to show one marker, which is perfectly working fine when view controller is being pushed to the navigation stack.

```
 func testCode() {
    mapView.layoutIfNeeded()
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {

   let camera = GMSCameraPosition(latitude: 31.326137, longitude: 75.575520, zoom: 10)
        self.pickupMarker = GMSMarker()
        self.addMarkerOnMap(lat: "31.326137", long: "75.575520", img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "drop-icon"), mapVieww: self.mapView,marker: &(self.pickupMarker), title: "Drop at", snippet:"Hello")
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setValue(Int(1), forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
    self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
CATransaction.commit()
               })
}
```

[image: Accurate Location when pushed]

[image: InAcurate camera position when presented]

Answer (score 1):

**I did Four things to resolve this issue.**

1. Take a container first where I want my map view, in the storyboard and make an outlet in the class.
2. Remove mapview outlet and remove mapview UIVIew from a storyboard also.
3. Programmatically add GMSMapView as a subview in a container (where I want to show the map).
4. Add code in viewdidappear method in Dispatchqueue and everything is now working fine.

Comment: You are a live saver :) ..